# Why is my precondition being ignored on my Property-based test?

Tags: f#, property-based-testing

Why is my precondition being ignored on my Property-based test?

**The precondition for my test is the following:**

```
fun rowCount -> rowCount >= 0
```

**Thus, my actual test is:**

```
[<Fact>]
let ``number of cells in grid equals rowcount squared`` () =
    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure <| 
            fun rowCount -> rowCount >= 0 ==>  
                            fun rowCount -> rowCount |> createGrid
                                                     |> Map.toList
                                                     |> List.length = rowCount * rowCount
```

**However, my test continues to fail:**

> Result Message:    System.Exception : Falsifiable, after 3 tests (1
>   shrink) (StdGen (985619705,296133555)): Original: 1
>   -1 Shrunk: 0
>   -1

**Domain:**

```
let createGrid rowCount = 

    [for x in 0..rowCount-1 do
        for y in 0..rowCount-1 do
            yield { X=x; Y=y; State=Dead } 
    ]|> List.map (fun c -> (c.X, c.Y), { X=c.X; Y=c.Y; State=Dead })
     |> Map.ofList
```

**[UPDATE]**

I've also tried:

```
let precondition rowCount =
    rowCount >= 0

let ``some property`` rowCount = 

    precondition rowCount ==> rowCount |> createGrid 
                                       |> Map.toList
                                       |> List.length = rowCount * rowCount
[<Fact>]
let ``number of cells in grid equals rowcount squared`` () =
    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure <| ``some property``
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       Property -> 'a     but given a
>       int -> Map<(int * int),Cell>     The type 'Property' does not match the type 'int'

Comment: Your property takes _two_ arguments - `rowCount` and second `rowCount`, - not one.

Comment: I'm confused: let ``some property`` rowCount = ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FyodorSoikin points out in his comment, you have two nested functions that each take a `rowCount`.

The *second* `rowCount` value shadows the first one, but the `==>` precondition function only works on the *first* `rowCount` value. Thus, the `rowCount` value actually used for testing is still unbounded.

Make the test simpler, and it'll work:

```
open Xunit
open FsCheck

[<Fact>]
let ``number of cells in grid equals rowcount squared`` () =
    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure <| fun rowCount ->
        rowCount >= 0 ==>  
        (rowCount
            |> createGrid
            |> Map.toList
            |> List.length = rowCount * rowCount)
```